# Yii and Database approach

Tags: sql, yii, rdbms

I am building an application in yii . I have experience with both AR and DAO but since my application is data heavy I will be using only DAO for all CRUD tasks .

However I am stuck on what kind of DB schema to go for , I am quite familiar to RDBMS but given that for data validation/displaying data in views I would have to create objects of their respective models . A user in my application hsa various fields that they can choose to fill/not fill . The fields are like :
1) Address related fields(broken down into seperate entities) 
2) Phone numbers(of multiple types) 
3) Accreditations (string data) 
4) Niche Specialiation (string data) 
5) Timings( selected from a drop down )
6) Facilities (string data)

And so on , note that these are only about 30% of all the fields .

While designing an RDBMS I would naturally put my phone numbers in one table , address in another and so on . For displaying a single view I am looking at creating around approximately 10-20 model objects . However this single view page that I am talking about is the heart of the application and functionality cannot be compromised here .

Given all these considerations , is RDBMS really the way to go if I have to account for scalability and PERFORMANCE in the future .

What other database options should I go for ?

Comment: When I use yii's app with DB > 4`000`000 records with many relations, I do not have any difference in DAO or AR query. But in AR I write code faster, and I do not member all changes in DB and I do not rewrite whole projects if I use DAO

Comment: Sounds good , but how many object declarations of either Cmodel/Cactive record typ do you typically pass to the view from the controller ? When I am done with my application I would be passing close to 20 objects of Cmodel class to my views .

Comment: It's realize with relations, and I do not special select or found. Like 'Post' -> 'Author' -> 'Address.email'. Just I set 'together' in relation for `one select` query

Answer (score 0):

The true power of using AR with Yii is when you take advantage of the model 'relations' (including numerous features added after the original 1.1 release). Also defining 'scopes' can be very powerful, as is the use of 'with'. All these features allow you to write the relation definition once. It may take a little time, but then you know every time you use it it's correct and they can be combined which is when AR shines.

There is some overhead in creating the model objects. You can still get higher performance by using Yii's extensive caching features. I haven't measured but I can easily believe that AR with caching can vastly outperform DAO without.